Getting AccessDenied while accessing getAllSites() method in MS Graph using Java
Getting AccessDenied error while accessing getAllSites() method in MS Graph using Java. I have taken this block of code from Microsoft Learn. When I tried to execute this code, I'm receiving Access Denied error. Please find below the Java code block.
final UsernamePasswordCredential credential = new UsernamePasswordCredentialBuilder()
            .clientId(clientId).tenantId(tenantId).username(userName).password(password)
            .build();

final GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(credential, scopes);

GetAllSitesGetResponse getAllSitesGetResponse = graphClient.sites().getAllSites().get();

List<Site> value = getAllSitesGetResponse.getValue();

Please find below the error which I'm receiving while executing the code.
Exception in thread "main" com.microsoft.graph.models.odataerrors.ODataError: Access denied
    at com.microsoft.graph.models.odataerrors.ODataError.createFromDiscriminatorValue(ODataError.java:36)
    at com.microsoft.kiota.serialization.JsonParseNode.getObjectValue(JsonParseNode.java:212)
    at com.microsoft.kiota.http.OkHttpRequestAdapter.lambda$throwIfFailedResponse$0(OkHttpRequestAdapter.java:674)
    at com.microsoft.kiota.ApiExceptionBuilder.<init>(ApiExceptionBuilder.java:26)
    at com.microsoft.kiota.http.OkHttpRequestAdapter.throwIfFailedResponse(OkHttpRequestAdapter.java:673)
    at com.microsoft.kiota.http.OkHttpRequestAdapter.send(OkHttpRequestAdapter.java:281)
    at com.microsoft.graph.sites.getallsites.GetAllSitesRequestBuilder.get(GetAllSitesRequestBuilder.java:60)
    at com.microsoft.graph.sites.getallsites.GetAllSitesRequestBuilder.get(GetAllSitesRequestBuilder.java:46)

I'm using the latest Graph dependency.
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.graph</groupId>
    <artifactId>microsoft-graph</artifactId>
    <version>6.13.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.graph</groupId>
    <artifactId>microsoft-graph-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.14</version>
</dependency>

I need help in listing all the sites from the sharepoint and to download a file from one of the site. Thanks for the guidance in advance.

Get all sites doesn't support delegated permissions, you can't access this method on behalf of a user.
You need to grant application permission Sites.Read.All and use client secret or certificate for authentication.
